# Mock methods that receives a block as parameter

Tags: ruby, testing, mocking, ruby-mocha

I have a scenario more or less like this

```
class A
  def initialize(&block)
    b = B.new(&block)
  end
end
```

I am unit testing class A and I want to know if B#new is receiving the block passed to A#new. I am using Mocha as mock framework.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this with both Mocha and RSpec and although I could get a passing test, the behavior was incorrect.  From my experiments, I conclude that verifying that a block is passed is not possible.

Question: Why do you want to pass a block as a parameter?  What purpose will the block serve?  When should it be called?

Maybe this is really the behavior you should be testing with something like:

```
class BlockParamTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_block_passed_during_initialization_works_like_a_champ
    l = lambda {|name| puts "Hello #{name}"}
    l.expects(:call).with("Bryan")
    A.new(&l) 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
l = lambda {}
B.expects(:new).with(l)
A.new(&l)
```

I know this works with RSpec, I'd be surprised if Mocha doesn't handle

Comment: Didn't work. I am starting to believe I cant do that in this way. I will try another approach here. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is `B::new` yielding to the block and does the block modify a param that `yield` provides? If yes, then you can test it this way:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'mocha/setup'

describe 'A' do

  describe '::new' do

    it 'passes the block to B' do
      params = {}
      block = lambda {|p| p[:key] = :value }
      B.expects(:new).yields(params)

      A.new(&block)

      params[:key].must_equal :value
    end

  end

end
```